# Problema/Duda Error al Conectar Con Base De Datos SQL Server Desde Una Clase En C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un pequeño problema, soy estudiante y lo que pasa es que no se quiere conectar correctamente a mi base de datos en Sql server, en c# cree una clase que se llama Sgd_Conexion que sirva para la conexión a la base de datos pero no se conecta agradecería si me pudieran ayudar:

aquí el código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Sgd_Conexion
    {
        private String _conexionString;
        public String ConexionString
        {
            get { return _conexionString; }
            private set { _conexionString = value; }
        }
        internal Sgd_Conexion()
        {
            ConexionString = "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=GestionDocumental; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuro la siguiente clase:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
// importo los siguientes espacios de nombre a la clase para trabajar con APP.Config
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Sistema_Control_Personal.Clases
{
    class Conexion
    {
        public string LeerConexion()
        {
            try
            {

                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

y configuro el archivo App.config para manejar la cadena de conexión:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="conexion" connectionString="Data Source=MYPC\MYPC;Initial Catalog=MYBD;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  
</configuration>
```

espero haberte ayudado